# Нужен ли дефис?

Tags: пунктуация

Нужен ли дефис: "оценивать с позиций «нравственно-безнравственное»"?

Answer (score 1):

Смысл опеределения совершенно непонятен. "Кисло-сладкое" еще можно понять, но "кисло-некислое" в голове не укладывается. Правила орфографии (правописания в целом) на такие случаи не распространяются.  
Возможно, вы имели в виду антонимию "нравственное - безнавственное", тогда необходимо тире, если речь идёт о философском противопоставлении, или дефис, но без кавычек, если используется как условное наименование.  Это, правда, по наитию, правил я вам сейчас не дам.

Answer (score 0):

Через дефис пишутся сложные прилагательные, если между частями сложного слова можно поставить союз *и*, например: *кисло-сладкий* = *кислый* и *сладкий*. В вашем случае непонятно, как объединить в одно сложное слово два антонима. По аналогии с вашим прилагательным может ли быть, например вкусно-безвкусный или сильно-бессильный?

Скорее всего, действительно, имеется в виду антонимическая пара "нравственное - безнравственное". Но тогда нужно писать два полных прилагательных через тире.